# For anidado en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Buenas, tengo una lista y quiero **iterar** sobre ella, y luego adentro de ese `for` iterar sobre la misma lista desde el siguiente valor que leí hasta el final.

En un estilo de programación tipo Java sería:

```
int[10] array;
for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++)
    for (int j=i+1; j < array.length(); j ++)
        //hacer algo con el array comparando los valores de a[i] y a[j]
```

Como puedo hacer esto en pyhton?
En principio tenia esto:

```
for a in array:
     del array[0]
     for a2 in array:
         //hacer algo con el array comparando los valores de a y a2
```

Pero me funciona solo para la primera iteración.. alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer pero puedes usar `enumerate` de la siguiente forma:

```
for i, item in enumerate(array):
    for item2 in array[i:]:
        # some code
```

Si clarificas un poco mejor la pregunta quizá podamos encontrar una respuesta más apropiada :-)

Answer (score 0):

La manera más simple y eficaz es usando `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

for (a, b) in combinations(array,  2):
  #comparar los dos elementos del array 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Este seria el código en Python

```
int[10] array;
for i in array
    for j in array[i+1:len(j)]
        // hacer algo con los valores de i y j
```

Answer (score 0):

Para definir un arreglo en python no es necesario definir el tamaño de este, al momento de declararlo puedes dejarlo vacio o definir los valores inmediatamente:

Sin valores:

```
arreglo = []
```

Con valores:

```
arreglo = [5,8,9,4]
```

Recuerda que las listas en python pueden crecer dinámicamente con la función `append()`.

Para el manejo de los ciclos for como tu lo quieres, es de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in range(len(arreglo)):
    for j in range((i+1), len(arreglo)):  
        print(arreglo[j])
```

Esta sintaxis es para [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

La función `len()` viene predefinida y nos devuelve el tamaño del arreglo. El rango en el ciclo for siempre comenzará en `0` a menos que se especifique otro valor como en el caso del segundo for.